# Get source element with Selenium or pywebcopy

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a site (https://www.scoresway.com/en_GB/soccer/eerste-divisie-2022-2023/1w03tfpd5nc6woo8j2nc9239w/match/view/50ytn2x7zvgjl6v7lunp4eh3o/player-stats) with python. When I use pywebcopy's save_website() I don't get the folder and file shown in the screenshot.
[image]

Probably this has to do with it being an API with authentication as the other folders show up. Is there a way to get the file I want in an other way? Or maybe I have to wait till the data is retrieved from the API?

Code I used:

```
from pywebcopy import save_website

save_website(
url='https://www.scoresway.com/en_GB/soccer/eerste-divisie-2022-2023/1w03tfpd5nc6woo8j2nc9239w/match/view/50ytn2x7zvgjl6v7lunp4eh3o/player-stats',
project_folder="savedpages//",
project_name="my_site",
bypass_robots=True,
debug=True,
open_in_browser=False,
delay=None,
threaded=False
)
```

Scraping the site source with Selenium also doesn't have this json in it.

Comment: did you try with CTRL+S to save the whole page?

Comment: yeah, that saves everything but not the folder/file I want.